# SIGSEGV in C function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have problem with my function.

When the function gets such a parameter, everything is ok

`char  text[50] = "Liquorice gummies macaroon";`

but when I send this one I get SIGEGV

```
char  *text = "Liquorice gummies macaroon";
```

My function:

```
char *sort(char *text) {

    int length = strlen(text);
    char *sortString = text;

    if (length >1){
        shell_sort(sortString, length);
        return sortString;
    } else if(length == 1) {
        return text;
    }
}
```

In function sort I call shell_sort

```
void shell_sort(char *text, int size) {

    int gap, temp, i , j;

    for (gap = size/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {

        for (i = gap; i<size; i++) {
            temp = text[i];

            for (j = i; j >= gap ;j-=gap) {
                if (temp < text[j-gap]) {
                    text[j] = text[j-gap];
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            text[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but when I send this one I get SIGEGV
>
> char  *text = "Liquorice gummies macaroon";

That's because your function `shell_sort()` modifies the argument passed to it, and modifying a string literal is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That's why it results in a segfault (btw, segfault is not guaranteed by the C standard).

> When the function gets such a parameter, everything is ok
>
> char  text[50] = "Liquorice gummies macaroon";

When you initialize a `char` array from a string literal, the string literal is *copied* into the array, which you can modify. So it works as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please Is there a simple solution on repair this error ?

Comment: You already know the solution. Use an array (`char text[50]`) if you want to be able to modify it.